# C - sscanf ignoring comma from csv file and reading the same piece of data twice

Tags: c, csv, parsing

I am trying to read from a CSV file into struct. For some reason, the value for social security numbers is also reading the address and them the address is being read a second time into newBin.address. It looks like the sscanf is ignoring the comma that separates the socials and address when it reads the file but then does register it when it moves on reading the address. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define STRSIZE 70

typedef struct BIN_DATA {
        unsigned int user_number;
        char name[32];
        char social_security[10];
        char address[32];
} BIN_DATA;

int main()
{
    // Define variables.
    FILE *in, *out;
    char str[STRSIZE];

    // New BIN.
    BIN_DATA newBin;

    // Open files.
    in = fopen("updated.txt", "r");


    // Check files.
    if(in == NULL)
    {
            puts("Could not open file");
            exit(0);
    }

    while(fgets(str, STRSIZE, in) != NULL)
    {
            memset(&newBin, '\0', sizeof(BIN_DATA));
            sscanf(str, "%6u, %[^,], %[^,], %[^\n\r]", &newBin.user_number, newBin.name,\
                            newBin.social_security, newBin.address);
            printf("%u. %s. %s. %s.\n", newBin.user_number, newBin.name,\
                            newBin.social_security, newBin.address);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

File being read:

```
289383,Estefana Lewey,591-82-1520,"9940 Ohio Drv, 85021"
930886,Burl Livermore,661-18-3839,"226 Amherst, 08330"
692777,Lannie Crisler,590-36-6612,"8143 Woods Drv, 20901"
636915,Zena Hoke,510-92-2741,"82 Roehampton St, 47905"
747793,Vicente Clevenger,233-46-1002,"9954 San Carlos St., 55016"
238335,Lidia Janes,512-92-7402,"348 Depot Ave, 29576"
885386,Claire Paladino,376-74-3432,"587 Front Ave, 32703"
760492,Leland Stillson,576-55-8588,"9793 Boston Lane, 08610"
516649,Wes Althouse,002-58-0518,"8597 Annadale Drive, 06514"
641421,Nadia Gard,048-14-6428,"218 George Street, 29150"
```

Comment: Hello. You should know that your `scanf` will fail on columns that have special characters as values. For example the string may be "8597 Annadale\n Drive". That being said, all your next `scanf`'s will read wrong data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there a way to fix that failure for special characters?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `social_security` member does not allocate enough space to hold the data you're reading.  It needs to be at least 12 to hold the SSN as written with a terminator at the end.

As for the format string you use with sscanf(), it's nearly correct.  However, you'll want to bound the maximum string length to match what you have storage for, so for example with `name` of 32 you should limit it to 31 characters saving one at the end for the terminator.

I changed the `social_security` field to `char social_security[12];` and then changed the format string to sscanf to be the following:

```
"%6u, %31[^,], %11[^,], %31[^\n\r]"
```

I was able to run the modified code with the sample input file to get the output you described.  You can try it too at the link:

[Runnable code](https://onlinegdb.com/rJAXEGqPw)

Comment: Awesome thank you! That work, I think the reason that the social char was set to 10 is that I am supposed to trim the '-' out, I was just taking it one step at a time. That is the next issue I will work on.

Comment: Note that this will capture the double quotes around the address, and it wouldn't work well if the address was not in the last column.  Doing the job properly requires library code — not very big or complex library code, but it requires code designed to deal with CSV format, in general.  See also [RFC 4180 — Comma-Separated Variable Format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).